# -Wstrict-overflow doesn't produce any warnings where it clearly should

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings

According to the g++ man-page and their website https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html , the following code should produce a warning when compiled with -O3 -Wstrict-overflow=5 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int
main() {
    int x{std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
    if(x+1 > x) std::cout << "Hello";
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/57ccc33f3

It even outputs "Hello", showing that it optimized the check(x+1 > x) away. However I get no warning. Do I misunderstand what this warning is meant to do or is this a gcc bug? I couldn't find anything in their bug database.

Comment: "Bug" is a bit strong. There's never a guarantee that the compiler will be able to detect all overflows, no matter how obvious they seem to you. For what it's worth, it does seem to detect the overflow when the variable is compile time constant.

Comment: *"-Wstrict-overflow=1"* *"Warn about cases that are both questionable and easy to avoid. For example the compiler simplifies x + 1 > x to 1."*. Your case is even level 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely a bug introduced between GCC [7.5](https://godbolt.org/z/6zTf1rr1x) and [8.1](https://godbolt.org/z/7748rsEPv). Be sure to report it. This particular example is even in the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: I would even say even before, as level 1 should already warns it according to their doc...

Comment: Then I will. I wanted to make sure first that I didn't overlook something.